# Can this type of flash dragging, dropping, and animation be done in a javascript library?

Tags: javascript, animation

Sorry.  I don't know a good title for this, but please look here:

http://joshblog.net/projects/logic-gate-simulator/Logicly.html

I saw this from delicious over the weekend.  It is in flash and I wondered if something like this, as far as the graphics and interaction goes, could be done in javascript (jquery or other library, *not* rolling my own.)

Again, I do not mean logic gates specifically but more the dragging, dropping and the drawing lines between objects, moving them around, etc.

Does anyone know of a website that has something like this in javascript?  It kind of reminds me of dragging and dropping points on google maps but nicer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like someone has recently made a [Logic Gate Thing](http://knolleary.net/code/logic/) that might interest you, though it doesn't quite have the level of animation that the Flash version has.  ([Here](http://knolleary.net/2009/03/24/logic-gate-thing/) is an explanation from the author.)

Comment: +1 It would be hard to find a more specific answer than that.

Comment: Wow dude... that IS an awesome answer.

Answer (score 3):

http://javascript.neyric.com/wireit/ and jQuery draggables is what you want.

Too bad the wire-it library is YUI. Would be nice if it were jQuery.

Comment: Why would it be any better if it were in jQuery?

Comment: Unfortuately, this breaks in my IE8 with: 

Webpage error details

Message: 'parentNode' is null or not an object
Line: 103
Char: 7
Code: 0
URI: http://javascript.neyric.com/wireit/lib/excanvas.js


on the demos and interactive documentation.  But it looks like what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: :( Indeed, seems to work fine in FF, I tried out the game in IE, no die.

Comment: @Daniel, because the draggables are pretty easy to work with in jQuery UI, so it makes an easy solution.

Comment: @altCognito: YUI has a Drag & Drop library as well.  (Never used it before, though.)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI has some effects such as dragging and animations. There are some demos at http://jqueryui.com/demos/

Answer (score 0):

Im sure you could work something similar with jQuery.  Checkout the jQuery UI, they have [demos](http://jqueryui.com/demos/) of its capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

[Mootools](http://mootools.net/) can also do this - they have some pretty slick demos on their website.